# The mobile close menu is very bold

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web, close-dialog

I just voted to close something on the mobile website, and the amount of bolded text threw me off. The first screen isn't so bad because of the text color difference which softens the blow:

[image: Main close menu]

However, after selecting the off-topic option, the new screen was quite overwhelming with bolded text:

[image: Off-topic close menu]

Can this bolding be fixed so that it's more pleasant to look at?

Comment: So, you want all caps?

Comment: thanks for reporting. i will take care about that.

Comment: @Paweł almost a month later, any update?

Comment: coming in few hours. thanks for reporting that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. It should be fixed now in production.